# mysql get last modify date for data

Tags: mysql, date

I wanna get last date when i make change in tables something like update add remove so not last modify date that table structure have been changed!

is there any way to catch this?

Answer (score 1):

There is a way. But involves either writing a trigger to insert information into a "log table", or adding a `last_update_time` column to your table and keeping it up to date always. There is no **automatic** way of doing it.